# Laravel 5 Form request, require input on create, but optional on edit

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6, laravel-validation, laravel-request

I am using laravel 5.6 `resources controllers` and `form request` the problem is that i have some inputs that are `required` on created, but on edit are optionals like file inputs. So i have this form request

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class ProgramRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            //
            'name.*'        => 'required',
            'description.*' => 'required',
            'logo'          => 'required|image|max:3000',
            'logo_alt'      => 'required|image|max:3000'
        ];
    }
}
```

the fields `logo` and `logo_alt` must be sent when creating the program, but when editing it sending a `logo` is optional.

is there a way to validate both cases with the same `form request` or i have to create a different `form request` for editing and for creating?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `$this->method()` to check which request method has been used and show different rules for each case:

```
public function rules()
    {
        switch($this->method())
        {
            case 'GET':
            case 'DELETE':
            {
                return [];
            }
            case 'POST':
            {
                 return [
                   'name.*'        => 'required',
                   'description.*' => 'required',
                   'logo'          => 'required|image|max:3000',
                   'logo_alt'      => 'required|image|max:3000'
                ];
            }
            case 'PUT':
            {
                return [
                   'description.*' => 'required',
                   'logo'          => 'nullable|image|max:3000',
                   'logo_alt'      => 'nullable|image|max:3000'
                ];
            }
            case 'PATCH':
            {
                return [];
            }
            default:break;
        }
    }
```

In this above example the `POST` will be for your create and the `PUT` will be for your update.

Notice I've used `nullable` for the `PUT` validation rules, this tells the request object that the field is optional.

Comment: Is there any way so we no need to repeat the validation? something like use switch case put only for field description. Thank you for this answer btw

Answer (score 3):

Instead of:

```
 return [
            //
            'name.*'        => 'required',
            'description.*' => 'required',
            'logo'          => 'required|image|max:3000',
            'logo_alt'      => 'required|image|max:3000'
        ];
```

you can use:

```
$rules =  [
    'name.*'        => 'required',
    'description.*' => 'required',
    'logo'          => ['image', 'max:3000'],
    'logo_alt'      => ['image', 'max:3000'],
];

if ($this->isMethod('POST')
{
   $rules['logo'][] = 'required';
   $rules['logo_alt'][] = 'required';
}

return $rules;
```

So basically you have rules for update but in addition for POST method you make logo and logo_alt required. You could use pipe syntax `|` too, but it's more convenient to use array syntax for rules so you can later do such things when needed.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late. But I found some better solustion like this

```
$requiredOrNull = '';
switch ($this->method()) {
    case 'POST':
        $requiredOrNull = 'nullable';
        break;
    case 'PUT':
        $requiredOrNull = 'required';
        break;
}
return [
      //
      'name.*'        => 'required',
      'description.*' => 'required',
      'logo'          => $requiredOrNull . '|image|max:3000',
      'logo_alt'      => $requiredOrNull . '|image|max:3000'
  ];
}
```

Basically it check if the method is post, your `logo` and `logo_alt` would be required, but if the method is put, it would be nullable

Comment: I think you need to remove `required` from the last two lines because they are filled with the variable declared inside switch statement.